# Understand whether code sample is CPU bound or Memory bound

Tags: c, performance, optimization, sse

As a general question to those working on optimization and performance tuning of programs, how do you figure out if your code is CPU bound or Memory bound? I understand these concepts in general, but if I have say, 'y' amounts of loads and stores and '2y' computations, how does one go about finding what is the bottleneck?

Also can you figure out where exactly you are spending most of your time and say, if you load 'x' amount of data into cache (if its memory bound), in every loop iteration, then your code will run faster? Is there any precise way to determine this 'x', other than trial and error?

Are there any tools that you'll use, say on the IA-32 or IA-64 architecture? Doest VTune help?

For example, I'm currently doing the following:

I have 26 8*8 matrices of complex doubles and I have to perform a MVM (matrix vector multiplication) with (~4000) vectors of length 8, for each of these 26 matrices. I use SSE to perform the complex multiplication.

```
/*Copy 26 matrices to temporary storage*/
for(int i=0;i<4000;i+=2){//Loop over the 4000 vectors 
    for(int k=0;k<26;k++){//Loop over the 26 matrices
       /*
        Perform MVM in blocks of '2' between kth matrix and 
        'i' and 'i+1' vector
       */     

    }
}
```

The 26 matrices take 26kb (L1 cache is 32KB) and I have laid the vectors out in memory such that I have stride'1' accesses. Once I perform MVM on a vector with the 27 matrices, I don't visit them again, so I don't think cache blocking will help. I have used vectorization but I'm still stuck on 60% of peak performance.

I tried copying, say 64 vectors, into temporary storage, for every iteration of the outer loop thinking they'll be in cache and help, but its only decreased performance. I tried using _mm_prefetch() in the following way: When I am done with about half the matrices, I load the next 'i' and 'i+1' vector into memory, but that too hasn't helped.

I have done all this assuming its memory bound but I want to know for sure. Is there a way?

Comment: what OS are you using?

Comment: Linux. But how does the OS matter in this case? I'm running it on a cluster using job scheduling, so there are no other processes running..

Comment: I'm curious, have you tried using `perf`?

Comment: @amdn actually no, perf wasn't installed and I had trouble getting them to install it. I used VTune instead. Also I rearranged my code and now its giving peak performance, it wasn't memory bound after all

Comment: I'm glad you were able to improve the performance!

Comment: Why are not using BLAS? They usually have the best possible implementation of Linear Algebra stuff

Comment: I don't really understand your explanation.  For a vector x are you left-multiplying by each to the 26 matrices A_i?  I.e. x'=A_26*A_25*...*A_1*x?  Where are you storing the result x'?  In the same place x was originally stored?  Surely you aren't multiplying each vector by the _same_ 26 matrices?!  If so then multiply the 26 A_i beforehand so that A=A_26*A_25*...*A_1, and then just left multiply each x by A.

Comment: @RSFalcon7: I can't use BLAS because these are small sized MVM's and the overhead (library calls) will be high.

Comment: @DouglasB.Staple: The number of matrices will at maximum be 26 and they won't change, but not all will be used for each input vector, also the order in which they get multiplied, won't be the same. The result for each input vector multiplied by its subset of the 26 matrices, will be stored in a separate output vector. The basic idea is to group together input vectors which have common matrices and try to perform an MMM.
The code above was for illustration, not the exact pseudocode.

Comment: In general when optimizing C code in linux and OS X I profile with valgrind+kcachegrind and attack the bottleneck.  kcachegrind will tell you how much time is spent doing which instruction in your code.  If all the time is going to e.g. add and multiple instructions then you're probably CPU limited.  It might also be able to explicitly check for memory bandwidth issues, although I have never tried this.

Comment: @user1715122 Library calls cost has much as function of yours, compare your timings against BLAS and check out which one is the fastest

Comment: Have you tried Eigen?  It should be optimized for small matrices as well.  It uses SSE (but not AVX).  I'm curious about the performance.  It's very easy to use in case you have not tried it.

Comment: How are you defining peak performance?

Answer (score 1):

To my understanding the best way is profiling your application/workload. Based on the input data, the characteristic of the application/workload can significantly vary. These behaviors can  however be quantified with to few [phases](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=859657) Ref[[2](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=1261391&tag=1), [3](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1899021)] and a histogram can broadly tell the most frequent path of the workload to be optimized. The question that you are asking will also require benchmark programs [like SPEC2006, PARSEC, Media bench etc] for an architecture and is difficult to answer in general terms ( and is an active part of research in computer  architecture). However, for specific cases a quantitative result can be stated for different memory hierarchies.  You can use tools like:

- Perf
- OProfile
- VTune
- LikWid
- LLTng

and other monitoring and simulation tools to get the profiling traces of the application. You can look at performance counters like IPC, CPI ( for CPU bound) and memory access, cache misses, cache access , and other memory counters for determining memory boundedness.like IPC,   Memory access per cycle (MPC),  is often used to determine the memory boundedness of an application/workload.
To specifically improve matrix multiplication, I would suggest using a optimized algorithm as in [LAPACK](http://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/news_notes/clevescorner/winter2000.cleve.html).